# show html with pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

print "hellp world" :)

i want to ask you if exist a function or class hwo can show the html code like the browser's jobe

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [QtWebKit Module](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qtwebkit.html) within Qt. It incorporates webkit rendering engine. Whereas you can get access to Qt classes using python binding, you can use Qt official manual as help. Qt designer is also included into pyqt - you can try using it to design your application's GUI (I'm almost sure you'll be able to find web browser component or similar there).

As for using html tags to decorate labels and other components showing text, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932092/default-html-style-for-controls-in-the-qt-library) question.