# Apply stylesheet to HTML content in QTextEdit

Tags: qt, qtextedit, qtstylesheets

I have a `QTextEdit` where I do display some HTML. Could I apply a stylesheet to that very HTML content?

Do not confuse it with applying a Qt stylesheet to the `QTextEdit` (that I know). I want to change the appearance of what is in the `QTextEdit` widget ("HTML").

Related: [Default HTML style for controls in the Qt library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932092/default-html-style-for-controls-in-the-qt-library)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932092/default-html-style-for-controls-in-the-qt-library is interesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a look at [Qt ignores CSS in QTextDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730224/qt-ignores-css-in-qtextdocument) which uses QTextDocument and the defaultStyleSheet property / setDefaultStyleSheet() http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#defaultStyleSheet-prop

**Note** that QTextEdit only supports the following html subset http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html if you want to do more then that you are probably best of using the QWebkit or QWebEngine modules depending on which Qt version your targeting.

Answer (score 2):

As per Qt5, [many CSS properties are supported](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html#css-properties):

> The following table lists the CSS properties supported by Qt's [rich text](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext.html) engine.

The best way to apply them is to start your document with `<style>` and use classes. However the `<node style="">` attribute also works.